# How to mount a usb harddisk after a interrupted shred

Tags: storage, lsblk, shred

Shred command was interrupted by a unrelated and user induced system halt.

Now I'm not able to see the harddisk using `lsblk -l`. Tried on multiple linux systems.

This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/862997) (from [External HDD detected, but not recognised. Cannot mount, cannot format, cannot do partition](https://askubuntu.com/q/862664/567307)) points to external power which I doubt as cause since I was able to shred in first place.

```
journalctl -b

Nov 03 15:48:44 x kernel: usb 1-1.1.4: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
Nov 03 15:48:44 x kernel: usb 1-1.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=55aa, bcdDevice= 1.00
Nov 03 15:48:44 x kernel: usb 1-1.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
Nov 03 15:48:44 x kernel: usb 1-1.1.4: Product: ASMT1051
Nov 03 15:48:44 x kernel: usb 1-1.1.4: Manufacturer: asmedia
Nov 03 15:48:44 x kernel: usb 1-1.1.4: SerialNumber: 123456789012
Nov 03 15:48:44 x kernel: usb-storage 1-1.1.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Nov 03 15:48:44 x kernel: usb-storage 1-1.1.4:1.0: Quirks match for vid 174c pid 55aa: 400000
Nov 03 15:48:44 x kernel: scsi host6: usb-storage 1-1.1.4:1.0
Nov 03 15:48:44 x kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
Nov 03 15:48:44 x kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
Nov 03 15:48:45 x kernel: scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ASMT     2105             0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6              
Nov 03 15:48:45 x kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
Nov 03 15:50:47 x kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Nov 03 15:50:47 x kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
Nov 03 15:50:47 x kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
Nov 03 15:51:07 x kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Nov 03 15:51:07 x kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
Nov 03 15:51:07 x kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
Nov 03 15:51:07 x kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
Nov 03 15:51:07 x kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 0-byte physical blocks
Nov 03 15:51:14 x kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
Nov 03 15:51:21 x kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
Nov 03 15:51:21 x kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Nov 03 15:51:21 x kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
Nov 03 15:53:22 x kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Nov 03 15:53:22 x kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
Nov 03 15:53:22 x kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
Nov 03 15:53:43 x kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Nov 03 15:53:43 x kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
Nov 03 15:53:43 x kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
Nov 03 15:53:57 x kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
Nov 03 15:56:15 x kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
Nov 03 15:58:16 x kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Nov 03 15:58:16 x kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
Nov 03 15:58:16 x kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
Nov 03 15:58:37 x kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Nov 03 15:58:37 x kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
Nov 03 15:58:37 x kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
```

The shred command:

```
sudo shred -vzn 0 /dev/sdb
```

lsblk -l

```
NAME      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda         8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk  
sda1        8:1    0   100M  0 part  /boot/efi
sda2        8:2    0   250M  0 part  /boot
sda3        8:3    0 118.9G  0 part  
luks      254:0    0 118.9G  0 crypt 
Arch-swap 254:1    0   512M  0 lvm   [SWAP]
Arch-root 254:2    0 118.4G  0 lvm   /
```

Comment: hardware failure seems likely here

Comment: By "shred", do you mean the tool that "overwrite a file to hide its contents, and optionally delete it"? Can you add the actual command used? Also add the complete output of `lsblk -l`. Is this an external or internal drive?